# Why is ArcGIS Pro so much faster than ArcMap, especially when dealing with raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I began using ArcGIS Pro back in April or so. First I didn't really like the ribbon layout as it gives me a strong vibe of Microsoft products. But learning new things has always been exciting for me, therefore I kept at it.

Over the last couple of months, I found that ArcGIS Pro is so much faster at handling raster. For example, when I used ArcMap to do Extract by Mask on high-resolution aerial files, I had to leave the computer on after work so that it could be finished the next day. Sometimes I even had to leave it on for the entire weekend. However, now with ArcGIS Pro, similar tasks won't take longer than 10 mins. That difference is insane to me.

Does anyone else have similar experience? I'm wondering if anyone knows what fundamental changes Esri has made in ArcGIS Pro. Did they change the algorithms for most tasks? I find it unlikely since the ArcPy code is the same.

I don't have any software development experience, but I really want to learn a little bit more about it. Can anyone share with me how such a dramatic change transpired?

Comment: Are you now using ArcGIS Pro on the same computer you were previously using to run ArcMap?

Comment: @elrobis Yes. So it's a controlled variable. I have ArcMap 10.6.1 and Pro 2.2.1. Is there any way to record the run time of each process? It's probably in the Results.

Comment: All rasters are not the same. FIle format, tiling, overviews, band count and many other things matter. Could you add image info or gdalinfo about your rasters? You may have something that is exceptionally hard to handle for ArcMap.

Comment: Sure. Just give me a moment. I want to run a raster extract task on the same file and see how long it will take for each to complete it.

Comment: Pro is natively 64-bit versus ArcMap's 32-bit? There's a different graphics pipeline (Esri-built versus Microsoft's)? It's going to be due to a lot of stuff I expect. Pro opens slower than ArcMap, at least for me. Do you have parallel processing turned on in Pro? Background processing? (Esri employee)

Comment: Simple extract by mask should not require much computing, it is mostly about how to get the correct pixels picked out from the source image. If the format does not support random access to data well it may require huge amounts of memory and disk swapping. In that case 32 bit vs. 64 bit can explain a lot.

Comment: I found ArcGIS Pro to be much better with rasters than ArcMap in nearly every respect. Visualizing them, for starters, was much easier.

Comment: @user30184 I guess you are right. What does "random access to data" mean? And if the format does not support it, how would one gain access to the data within at all?

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks a lot for the reply. I didn't know Pro is 64-bit and Map is 32-bit. I heard that 64-bit is faster and more powerful than 32-bit, but why tho? Another question, what is graphics pipeline? But if like you said, Pro uses Microsoft graphics pipeline, that'd explain why it gave me such a strong Microsoft vibe.

Comment: @mkennedy As for the questions that you asked me: 1.  I just heard of the parallel processing now from you. Where can I activate it? I couldn't find it. 2. I disabled background processing in ArcMap and couldn't find the option for ArcGIS Pro at all. A quick Google shows that Pro doesn't have background processing, but that's for 1.0. I'm not sure if it still holds true. Thanks.

Comment: With random access I mean some quich way to select the right pixels from a small region of the image. For example with JPEG and PNG images the whole image must be first read and decompressed even if you need only a few pixels.

Comment: The graphics pipeline is what handles drawing the data so wouldn't affect tools. Pro uses an Esri-built one which is optimized for GIS data and I think uses GPU where possible. ArcMap uses MS graphics engine/library/something. There's stuff we just couldn't fix in ArcMap because of the MS graphics.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you. That's contrary to what I think. Could you tell me how I can change the settings of background and parallel processing in Pro please?

Comment: background processing (not needed): https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012074  by the way, I'm googling this information because it doesn't impact my daily work

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/parallel-processing-factor.htm

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks. I found the same results yesterday. According to the first article, I don't need to modify the background processing setting in Pro as there is none. But that article was from 2016 so I thought something different has come up this year. And it seems like the parallel processing is available for only certain tools. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good to see that Pro is faster at some things....when it comes to editing, attributing,symbology, and labelling it's terrible compared to Map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's turn some of the comments into a partial answer. I'm an Esri employee but not involved in the guts of ArcGIS Pro so I'm going by what I've heard over the years and can find in the help.

ArcGIS Pro uses an Esri-built graphics engine, optimized for GIS data and which uses a GPU if available. ArcGIS Desktop uses the Microsoft graphics engine which had some limitations that we could not work around (transparency when printing).

ArcGIS Pro is natively 64-bit unlike ArcGIS Desktop. Thus, [64-bit background processing](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012074) is no longer needed. Tools are run asynchronously allowing other work in the application to be performed while a tool is running.

Some tools support [parallel processing](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/parallel-processing-factor.htm).

I do not know why rasters in particular seem to perform faster. Tools had to be ported/rewritten for Pro so there may have been some optimization that occurred.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted my previous comment right before seeing this. I think this is a great answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

well at least Pro is faster at something, everything else takes twice as long, esp. editing, symbology, and labels.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).